# Some photos in iPhoto showing as grey triangle with exclamation mark

Tags: macos, photos.app

I am unable to view/access some photos - I get a grey triangle with an exclamation mark in it.

[image]

Comment: Rotate clockwise/counterclockwise option IS ALSO GRAYED OUT

Answer (score 1):

Try repairing the library. Hold ⌘⌥ and open iPhoto, then choose Repair Database.

If that doesn't fix it, hold ⌘⌥ and open iPhoto again, and select Rebuild Database.

Comment: I've moved from iPhoto to Photos one year ago. I'm facing the same problem now, repairing Photos library didn't work and my last photo in iPhotos is from 2015. I'm a bit wary of repairing iPhotos without my latest pictures in it, concerned of what might happen to the Photos library.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the image and see the exclamation mark, select Photos from the menu bar and click on the dropdown that says "Revert to original". I did that because repairing and rebuilding the database didn't work for me, and magically the image re-appeared.

In most cases the photos had to be edited meaning I must have repositioned or edited them at some point. So, you might have to use the arrow to turn your photo upright.

Comment: What if "Revert to original" is grayed out in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Revert to original was grayed out for me too, so I tried "Rotate Clockwise" and that Worked!  I then selected "Rotate Counterclockwise" and the image was visible again in the proper orientation.

Answer (score 0):

After my update to Sierra, some of my photos appeared as grey triangles with an exclamation point too. I fixed it by selecting them and rotating the clockwise and counter clockwise. They didn't all change back immediately, but they all eventually reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue although neither the database rebuild or rotating worked for me. I notice when I right click and play slideshow though the image is still there but it's really low resolution and it can't be viewed any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem - triangle/exclamation point on all pictures in Photos on my MacBook Pro after a certain date.No clue why. All solutions in Images GREYED OUT, so I can't 'revert' or 'rotate'. This is what worked for me....I went to iCloud.com and downloaded all Triangled pictures. Then went to 'Downloads' and chose all pics, dragged/dropped them to Photos as 'new items' - cumbersome, but  everything is viewable on MacBook Pro in high res. Obviously, there's another simpler fix in some setting somewhere....but this worked.

Answer (score -1):

Turning them horizontally makes them appear for some odd reason.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: This is just a poor echo of an existing answer.